# PHP set a hourly limit Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, time

I'm trying to create a function with PHP and mysql to limit the number of requests per hour. I would like to keep it to PHP and Mysql, I would be using these to trigger other things.

I've been having issues with this and not really sure how to do this. What i have so far is bellow. As you can see it is not much. How can this be done?

```
$limit = 20;
$likecount = $owner->likecount = 1 + $owner->likecount;

$initialtime = $owner->initialtime= time();
$timeplushour = $owner->timeplushour = strtotime('+1 hour', $initialtime);

if($likecount <=$limit){

}
```

Comment: This question is quite vague. Can we see all of your code? "What I have so far below..." is very incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-resources.html), MySQL provides control over resource limits for each account (which corresponds to a row) in the `mysql.user` table.

Using the [`GRANT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) statement, we can specify the limits using the `MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR` and `MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR` option like this:

```
#create a new user
CREATE USER 'thisisme'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'thisisme'; 
GRANT ALL ON customer.* TO 'thisisme'@'localhost'
    WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 20     # restrict the number of queries to 20 per hour
         MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 10     # restrict the number of updates to 10 per hour
         MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 5; # restrict the number of connection to the server to 5 per hour
```